# MYSQL: left Join and sum two tables where one table has two columns referring to the first table

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I am trying to create a procedure where my `transfer` table is joined to my `account` table. In my `transfer` table, there are two FK columns that reference the `account` table `id` column.

account table:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    id              INT         NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    number          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    description     VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    is_active       BIT(1)      NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE account_name (name, number)
);
```

transfer table:

```
CREATE TABLE transfer (
    id              INT         NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date            DATE        NOT NULL,
    from_account    INT             NULL,
    to_account      INT             NULL,
    amount          DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (from_account)
        REFERENCES account(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (to_account)
        REFERENCES account(id)
);
```

get_account procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_account()
    SELECT a.*,
        (SUM(t.amount) - SUM(f.amount)) AS balance
    FROM account a
    LEFT JOIN transfer f
        ON a.id = f.from_account
    LEFT JOIN transfer t
        ON a.id = t.to_account
    GROUP BY a.id;
```

I am trying to subtract the total of the `from_accout` column from the total of the `to_account` column. I am able to get the sum of just one column but when I try to get both it returns a `NULL`.

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: the `(SUM(t.amount) - SUM(f.amount)) AS balance` is returning `NULL` but if I just do `SUM(f.amount) AS balance` I am getting the correct totals just for that one column.

Comment: have you tried `SUM(t.amount) AS balance` also?

Comment: That was it. It was because my `to_account` column is all `NULL`. I thought that would just sum it as '0'. Is there a way to force it to count it as 0 if there are no results?

Comment: `ISNULL(SUM(t.amount), 0) `

Comment: It is working with `IFNULL(SUM(t.amount))`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that COALESCE conforms to the ANSI standard